# Animating SVG with pure Javascript

Tags: javascript, animation, svg

I am trying to learn how to animate SVG's using pure vanilla Javascript. I want to make the circles grow and shrink while displaying a label on top of each circle with a value that represents its current size.

Sor far I have the following SVG:

```
  <svg width="500" height="300" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <path fill="none" d="M-1-1h502v302H-1z"/>
        <g>
          <path stroke-linecap="null" stroke-linejoin="null" stroke-opacity="null" stroke-width="4.5" stroke="#000" fill="none" d="M39.5 31.5v239M463.5 269.5l-422-1"/>
          <ellipse stroke="#bf0000" ry="65.5" rx="67" cy="165" cx="158.5" stroke-width="4.5" fill="none"/>
          <ellipse stroke="#007f00" ry="65.5" rx="67" cy="165" cx="361.5" stroke-width="4.5" fill="none"/>
        </g>
      </svg>
```

The following JS code:

```
console.log("DOM Ready!");

var redCircle = document.getElementsByClassName('red');

var current = 0;
var destination = 700;
var friction = 0.04;


function loop() {
  console.log(redCircle.style.width);
  current += (destination - current) * friction;
  redCircle.style.width = (current * 0.5 + 'px');
  if (current >= destination - 0.1) {
    clearInterval(animation);
  }
}
var animation = setInterval(loop, 20);
```

My issue is that the dev tools console.log says:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'width' of undefined at loop
```

Answer (score 1):

document.getElementsByClassName returns an array not an object.  Also you have no class named 'red' in your html so the array returned in your script is = []. An empty array.  When you call .style, you are basically calling [].style.  Since style does not exist as an attribute on an array(it is undefined).  You then try to get the attribute(.width) of something that does not exist([].style), which is impossible so Javascript can do nothing but throw an error.

```js
console.log("DOM Ready!");

var redCircle = document.getElementsByClassName('red');

var current = 0;
var destination = 700;
var friction = 0.04;

function loop() {
  // console.log(redCircle[0].style);
  current += (destination - current) * friction;
  redCircle[0].style.width = (current * 0.5 + 'px');
  if (current >= destination - 0.1) {
    clearInterval(animation);
  }
}
var animation = setInterval(loop, 20);
```

```html
  <svg width="500" height="300" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="red">
        <path fill="none" d="M-1-1h502v302H-1z"/>
        <g>
          <path stroke-linecap="null" stroke-linejoin="null" stroke-opacity="null" stroke-width="4.5" stroke="#000" fill="none" d="M39.5 31.5v239M463.5 269.5l-422-1"/>
          <ellipse stroke="#bf0000" ry="65.5" rx="67" cy="165" cx="158.5" stroke-width="4.5" fill="none"/>
          <ellipse stroke="#007f00" ry="65.5" rx="67" cy="165" cx="361.5" stroke-width="4.5" fill="none"/>
        </g>
      </svg>
```